# SharePoint 2013 Calculated Field not working all the time

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a form where I need to include a calculated field. I made a very simple test using a calculated field where the formula is "=ID". I just want to confirm that the value I'm getting in the view is the same as the ID of the record in the list.

I press NEW and create a new record. Then when I see the new record in the view, the first column is the ID (let's say 11), then some proper fields form the form and finally the calculated field that instead of showing me the value 11, it shows 0.

Then I follow the following steps:

1. I go to Settings, List Settings
2. Click on the calculated field to edit it (only edit it with no modifications) and press on OK (no modifications to the calculated field at all)
3. Go back to the list of records and now the calculated value shows me the value 11

I google it but no solution.. there is someone say that this issue is from the column ID, it mean 'when you initially save the item is that there is no value for "ID" yet' !
and this isn't my state, the column id is incremented normally when add new item.

Anyone can help me to identify with the calculated field does not shows 11 automatically after the record is saved?
or by follow another solution like using a workflow 2013..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have to follow those steps to get the calculated field to update? What happens if you wait 5-10 minutes after creating a new item and then refresh your list view?

Comment: I wait for a long time and i refreshed the list view but nothing was changed until i edited the calculated column then saved it

Answer (score 2):

You can **not** use [ID] in a Calculated Column formula.
*I won't bother with the long technical explanation...*

If it was possible, Microsoft would have added it to the list of Fields you can select when writing a Formula.

Workaround is to make a simple SharePoint Designer Workflow which kicks off on Item creation and saves the ID value to another Column.

You can then use that Column in your Calculated Formulas

If you're doing anything front-end.. jQuery.. CSR/JSlink.. the ID value is available in the attribute id of the Item TableRow (TR) as **x,id,y**
so you can get the id with

```
var ID={element}.getAttribute('id')[1]
```

#### Update #1 - example code used:

```
="<a href='/sites/ru1/Lists/ao26c/DispForm.aspx?ID=' 
     target='_blank'><img src= '_layouts/images/blank.gif' 
     onload= ""var row=this;
               while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode};
               this.parentNode.href+=row.‌​getAttribute('id').split(',')[1];
             "">Открыть</a>"
```

Comment: Sorry, but why i cant use [ID] in a Calculated Column formula, im sure that i was used it previously.

Comment: The id is getting evaluated and populated after your calculated field hence why you get '0'. I bet you'd find it works on an amend as opposed to a new event. Danny's suggestion is the best approach.

Comment: Hi. I try to use it, but I get JS error `Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined` (SP Foundation 2013). My formula: `= " <img src= ""_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload= ""alert({element}.getAttribute('id')[1])""  > "`

Comment: Oh, I found my mistake. Many thanks for this solution. My working code: `="<a href='/sites/ru1/Lists/ao26c/DispForm.aspx?ID=' target='_blank'><img src= '_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload= ""var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode};this.parentNode.href+=row.getAttribute('id').split(',')[1];"" >Открыть</a>"`

Comment: Only one problem: this column with this big code include to user alerts (default list alert) :(